# can we copy a file from android mobile app to a pc

Tags: android

I am trying to copy SD card image file from my pc using InputStream, OutputStream, FileInputStream and FileOutputStream. But the error comes at FileOutputStream as the values we are passing to this is desktop folder. The code is

```
File file = new File(path); \\ where 'path' is the sd card image file path
File destFolder = new File("D:\\images\\"); \\ I know this path is not correct. IP address of PC is missing here

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFolder);

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;

while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
     out.write(buf, 0, len);
}
in.close();
out.close();
```

When we can copy files from one system to another system, which are on same network, why can't we do that from mobile to pc when they are also on the same network connected through wifi.

If with the above method is not possible then What is the method to do this.

error is:

```
05-25 20:06:20.836 2576-2576/com.example.user.storeimage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.user.storeimage, PID: 2576

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)

at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)

at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\images\: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
                                                                           at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                                           at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
                                                                           at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
                                                                           at com.example.user.storeimage.copyimagetopc.onClickSaveBtn(copyimagetopc.java:52)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                        Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
                                                                           at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                                           at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                                           at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                                           at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87) 
                                                                           at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72) 
                                                                           at com.example.user.storeimage. copyimagetopc.onClickSaveBtn(copyimagetopc.java:52) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: Publish the error are you getting on the Logcat

Comment: @Roger RV: the app is closed saying "Unfortunately app is closed"

Comment: @Roger RV: the error code is included in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

`File` works for filesystem paths, for the local filesystem. In the case of Android, the local filesystem is the Android device. There is no `D:\\images\\` on an Android device. Android does not support mapping of SMB servers to filesystem paths.

> If with the above method is not possible then What is the method to do this.

Either work with SMB directly (e.g., jCIFS) or find some app that exposes SMB servers through some sort of API (e.g., a `ContentProvider`).

Answer (score 0):

As the following error and CommonsWare's answer, I think that you need to know that your mobile phone and your computer OS are in different hosts. So `D:\\images\\` is pointting to the same host address. You need to point to your LAN address and use a protocol like samba or the same windows sharer to share a folder and giving permissions or you can use a Webserver like `XAMPP` and send the file as a encoded base 64 String and decode then in the xampp server with php and save it to a folder.